# cordova CPU on an Android tablet

Tags: cordova

When we run a Cordova application in a Samsung tablet (Galaxy S3) it takes approx 40% of the CPU.   Are there settings that control how Cordova runs that would affect CPU so significantly.

Comment: Are you sure your app is responsible for this CPU load? Have you tried to factory reset the table to remove unwanted third party apps?